# What is the best way to make a deck with choosable positions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 24 cards from which you can choose 6. If you choose a card you have 6 different spots to put that card in (one for each choosable card).

How would you write the code in `java` for that, so that:

1. No Card can be chosen twice
2. If the card is already on a spot, you get to the information activity of that card if click that spot

I tried with array list in which I put the state of those spots as numbers, aswell as which cards are already chosen (as numbers).
However, that gets very much code and because of that the app is very slow...

So my question is: What's the best and efficient way to achieve such a deck-choose App?

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: its to much unfortunately, but it should basically be like in clash royal, if you know that game

Comment: Not the whole code, the piece which you feel is causing the issue

Answer (score 2):

i tried to keep the oop in mind, this is probably how you can implement logic for taking cards, it looks like lot of code but thats how java is

```
// i don't know what Card should have in your game so it's empty
    public static class Card {}

    public static class Deck {
        // cards are private as accessing card slots directly would defy purpose of deck
        private final CardSlot[] cards;

        public Deck(Card ...cards) {
            this.cards = new CardSlot[cards.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                this.cards[i] = new CardSlot(cards[i]);
            }
        }

        // there are multiple options how things can go wrong so we are throwing exceptions
        public Card takeCard(int pos) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalAccessException {
            if(pos < 0 || pos >= cards.length) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("you have to pull card from this deck");
            }

            if(cards[pos].taken) {
                throw new IllegalAccessException("card is already taken");
            }

            cards[pos].taken = true;

            return cards[pos].card;
        }

        private static class CardSlot {
            boolean taken;
            Card card;

            public CardSlot(Card card) {
                this.card = card;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Hand {
        // hand size should not change during game (or should depends on your game so final is optional)
        public final int size;
        // again exposing cards would defeat purpose of Hand class
        private Card[] cards;

        public Hand(int size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        // same as for deck we use exceptions
        public void addCard(int pos, Card card) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalAccessException {
            if(pos < 0 || pos >= cards.length) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("you have to put card into your hand");
            }

            if(cards[pos] == null) {
                throw new IllegalAccessException("card slot if already taken");
            }

            cards[pos] = card;
        }

        // try implement this
        public Card getCard(int pos) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Deck deck = new Deck(new Card(),/* enumerate all cards here */ new Card(), new Card());
        Hand hand = new Hand(6);
        
        // though avoid nesting try catch if possible
        try{
            Card card = deck.takeCard(3);
            try{
                hand.addCard(1, card);
            } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
                // handle exception, ask to insert card again
            } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // same here
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            // handle exception, ask to takeCard again
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // same here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a little bit more what you did here?

Comment: do you understand syntax?

Comment: like 80 % of it, just not the reason for some things. Could you make //*What you are doing in this line* after some key parts? Like to already did before each class, but also inside that class?